# How to run SQL server maintenance plan task on success of two other tasks

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to run the maintenance plan task on success of two other tasks and only after those tasks have completed. At the moment task2 starts straight away after one of the other two completes and it's not waiting for them both to finish.

[image]

Comment: Put them in a container.

Comment: there are no containers in sql server maintenance plan

Comment: SQL Agent Service can do this. When you create a job there you can set what task is to start after another

Comment: These are multiple jobs and I need to run them in specific order + I don't want to start them with  sp_start_job

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am able to add Execute SQL Agent Job Task to a Sequence Container in SSDT without any problem as far as I can tell.